# To insert unchecked value of a check box into database

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc, checkbox

I need help in inserting the unchecked value of a check box into mysql database using servlet.

**Work Flow:**

1.From a list of check box values the user checks some of the values and the remaining values are set unchecked

2.After selecting the values the user hits the save button

3.On clicking the save button,the checked values should be stored in one table and the unchecked values should be stored in another table

**Issue**

I have used the general method to insert the values into database,for me the checked values are getting inserted into one table(pdt_list).In the same way I need to insert the unchecked values into another table say(no_pdt_list). Both the insertion should happen once the save button is clicked.

This is my code

**products.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="web.Products"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <form method="post" action="Save_Products">   
<b>          
            Brand Name:<font color="green">
            <% String brand_name=(String)session.getAttribute("brand_name");
       out.print(brand_name);%> 
        <c:set var="brand_name" value="brand_name" scope="session"  />
       </font></b>         
            <table>            
                <tr>                
                    <th> Products</th> 
                    <th> Description </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
               <td> <b><%
      List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("list");
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
           out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" value=\""  + prod.getProductname() + "\">"  + prod.getProductname()+"<br>");
            } %> </b></td>   

            <td><%for(Products prod: pdts){
            out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" style=\"width:50px; height:22px\"/><br/>"); 
        } 

      }  
            %> </td>  

        </tr>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <tr><td align="center">  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/> </td></tr> 
            </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Servlet code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class Save_Products extends HttpServlet {
 static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pdt";
     static final String dbUser = "root";
     static final String dbPass = "root";
    @Override
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            ResultSet rs=null;
            Connection connection = null;  
            try{
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String brand_name =(String) session.getAttribute("brand_name");
String [] prod_list = request.getParameterValues("prod");
String [] desc_list = request.getParameterValues("desc");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection (dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);

String sql="insert into pdt_list(brand_name,product_name,desc)values(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
int num_values = Math.min(prod_list.size(), desc_list.size());

int count_updated = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < num_values; i++){
    prep.setString(1, brand_name);
    prep.setString(2, prod_list[i]);
    prep.setString(3,desc_list[i]);
    count_updated += prep.executeUpdate();
}
if(count_updated>0)
{    
   out.print("Products Saved Successfully...");
 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Save_Success.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);    
}
else{
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Save_Failure.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);   
}

prep.close();
       }
     catch(Exception E){
//Any Exceptions will be caught here
System.out.println("The error is"+E.getMessage());

    }  

        finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("The error is"+ex.getMessage());
            }
                }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Jquery as well?, you could try doing: 
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)") and saving it in a hidden field before submitting the form when you hit "Save"...

Be sure to reference the name of your checkbox if you have more than one set os checkboxes in your page.

i.e:

$("input#prod:not(:checked)").each(function(i){ 
   `console.log($(this).val()); //or save it to the hidden value with a comma or some sort of separator you can then work with at the servlet 
});`

Comment: When a save button is clicked, servlet is called .In the servlet implementation checked values should be stored in one table and the unchecked values in another table.Is it possible to handle two tables in a single servlet implementation?

Comment: Well I do it all the time with SQLJ files called from Servlets or AjaxServlets, I think it should work the same with mySql coding, as long as you do a proper control regarding openning and closing the connections, you can organize it better by adding private methods to your Servlet and call them from the doPost ...